# Comparing source files in Visual Studio community 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want to compare two source files in Visual Studio Community 2013. I tried VS help and it asks me to [connect to a team project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385990(v=vs.120).aspx) in order to compare files. Can I compare files without connecting to team project? I just use VS for my own use, not in a team.

The help [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385990(v=vs.120).aspx) also mentions about the in-built diff window but I am not able to find this window. Can somebody help please?

Comment: you may use kdiff3  :  http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks @Chaka for the link. However, if there is already an in-built tool, I would prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

I found it on the VS forum. If you want to compare file1.cpp and file2.cpp,

1. Go to **Start>All Programs>Visual Studio 2013>Visual Studio Tools.**. I was directed to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts.
2. Click on **Developer Command Prompt for VS2013**. A command prompt
       opens. I copied file1.cpp and file2.cpp in the current directory shown on the prompt. Otherwise go to the directory where both the files reside.
3. Type `devenv /Diff file1.cpp file2.cpp` and press enter.

A separate window of VS opens with the [diff window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj874068(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm still not sure if that can be done without the need to go to the command prompt.